# Designing an algorithm in Log N time

Tags: python, list, algorithm, iteration

I am having problems designing an algorithm, in Log N time, my algorithm will count all the indexes which satisfy this condition.

Say we have a List A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,18,20] , the list A is always sorted.

ALL INTEGERS IN LIST ARE UNIQUE

I need to find all the elements such that | A[i] - i | <= c. Where C is an integer passed in as input.

What I have tried so far, is the binary search algorithm, but I am not quite sure where to put the conditional checks

**MY CODE IS CURRENTLY A BINARY SEARCH**

```
low = 0
    high = len(arr) - 1


    while low <= high:

        mid = (high + low) // 2
        print(mid)
        if arr[mid] == x:
            return mid


        # Check if x is present at mid
        if arr[mid] < x:
            low = mid + 1

        # If x is greater, ignore left half
        else:
              high = mid - 1

        # If x is smaller, ignore right half


            # If we reach here, then the element was not present
    return -1
```

Comment: you have conditional checks there? whats the question?

Comment: are you sure this is possible?  Although `A` is sorted, I don't believe it's guaranteed that the list composed of `A[i] - i` for each `i` will be sorted, or will be guaranteed to have any structure.

Comment: Well this is what they have asked me to do, I don't think it has to be exactly in O(log N) time but it has to be better than O(n).

Comment: Input will always be in sorted order, and input will always be  a list.

Comment: @KevinWang as long as `A` is sorted and has only unique values, `A[i+1]-(i+1)` will be greater than or equal to `A[i]-i` since `A[i+1]=A[i]+n` where `n>=1`

Comment: try to find the max index for the condition that satisfies | a[i]-i | <=c.Then answer will be 0 index to that index. If you need more help ping me here

Comment: I don't understand can u write the psuedocode

Comment: What is the list made of? Integers? Unique?

Comment: It is a sorted list with UNIQUE integers

Answer (score 1):

**Given:**

List A is sorted and all the elements are unique, which means that the ***List A is strictly increasing***.

Assuming List A to be the 0th index.

**Observation:**

Suppose that we are going to build a list B for which each element at the index i is A[i]-i. You will observe that list B is always increasing(not strict).

**Proof:**

For list A,

suppose element at (i)th index be x.

B[i] = x-i

Then element at (i+1)th index will be greater than x with a minimum of (x+1).

So, minimum value of B[i+1] = (x+1)-(i+1) = x-i.

So, in the worst case in list B, value at (i+1)th index will be equal to the value at (i)th index.

**Example:**

List A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,18,20]   # Strictly Increasing

List B = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,11,12]   # Increasing

**Solution:**

As we need to solve this problem in O(log(n)) time, We should not construct List B while we should use List A and indices in doing a binary search.

That is the condition **A[mid] - mid**.

```
# Function performing binary Search
def binarySearch(c, A):
    low = 0
    high = len(A) - 1
    while low <= high:
        mid = low + (high-low+1)//2
        if A[mid]-mid > c:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1;
    return high;

A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,18,20]
num_Values = binarySearch(1, A)+1

# Number of values satisfying the condition (A[index] - index <=c)
print(num_Values)

# printing the values
for i in range(num_Values):
    print(A[i],end=" ")
```